# How to jsDoc a prototype for visibility in the entire project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsdoc

I am trying to do some jsDoc on this code:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} GameSmartAPI
 * @property {object} $api
 */

/** @type {GameSmartAPI} */
Vue.prototype.$api = { 
  myMethod() { /* Do stuff */ }
}
```

I am then using it in another file like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    this.$api.myMethod()
  },
  render: h => h(index)
})
```

This isn't picking `this.$api` in the project. So, what I would like to do is document the prototype `$api`, so that the other files know what `$api` is. Currently It does not know what `this.$api` is, and I get an editor error that say:

> Property '$api' does not exist on type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DataDef<Data, Record<PropNames, any>, Vue>, Methods, Computed, Array<PropNames>, Record<PropNames, any>> & ThisType<CombinedVueInstance<Vue, Data, Methods, Computed, Readonly<...>>>'

Comment: did you declare `Vue.use(...)` for your `$api` plugin?

Comment: No, but the code works, it's just not getting documented correctly.

Comment: This has all the look and smells of a plugin without you actually using a plugin - that could cause some issues with whatever editors intellisense. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin